# Memcache is required error - symfony on appengine

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

Created new project with appengine-starter-symfony-project (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project) and tried to run app/server as follows:

```
composer run-script server --timeout=0
```

Error recived:

```
 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug
 // false



  [Symfony\Component\Cache\Exception\CacheException]
  Memcached >= 2.2.0 is required
```

Running PHP Version 7.2.8 on Xampp (Win 10) and cant see a php_memcache in ext folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is the expected behavior. If you take a look inside of `config.yml` you will see the following:

```
services:
    memcache:
        class: Memcache
    session.handler.memcache:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler
        arguments:
          - "@memcache"
          - { prefix: ~, expiretime: ~ }
```

Basically, you cache is dependent on `Memchace`. You can either tweak around and switch to some other vendor or install the appropriate DLL.

Hope this helps a bit...

Comment: OK thanks, sorry but how do I install memcache into xampp? better for me to replicate production environment than change code/dependendcies

Comment: The project seems to run ok without it. I guess it comes into play more when the project is deployed to Google App Engine.